Remote connection from MacBook to ubuntu with RDP: Desktop is extended
When I connect via rdp it seems to be an extension to the server monitor. When I start a terminal session on the server it is opening on the rdp-monitor, if there is no connection it does not open at all.
I am new to Ubuntu so everything is interesting and difficult.
